# Query cosmos db document to filter documents

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am reading all documents from my cosmos db sql api collection and I would like to filter out those documents which has a specific property defined in the json. So if documents are of this schema

```
{
id: 1
name: aaa
project: ssdf
}
```

I would like to filter out documents which has "project" property in it. My code till now where I am able to read documents from collection:

```
 do
            {
                var feed = await client.ReadDocumentFeedAsync(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( SourceDatabase, SourceCollection ),
                    new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10, RequestContinuation = continuationToken } );
                continuationToken = feed.ResponseContinuation;
                foreach( Document document in feed )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( document );
                }
            }
```

The query by which I get filtered documents in Cosmos db is `select * FROM c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.Project)`. How do I do it in code above?

Updating Question after Gaurav's answer:

```
static async Task Main()
        {
            string continuationToken = null;
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( endpointUrl ), authorizationKey );
            var feed = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
                       UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( SourceDatabase, SourceCollection ).ToString(),
                       new SqlQuerySpec( "select * FROM c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.Project)" ),

                       new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 100, EnableCrossPartitionQuery=true } ) ;
            continuationToken = feed.
                
                foreach( Document document in feed )
                {
                   
                   Console.WriteLine( document.Id );
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're using version 2.0 of the Cosmos DB SDK. If that's the case, then you can use [`CreateDocumentQuery(String, String, FeedOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_CreateDocumentQuery_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_) method to execute a query.

Here's an example to do the same:

```
// SQL querying allows dynamic property access
dynamic document = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(collectionLink,
    "SELECT * FROM books b WHERE b.title == 'War and Peace'").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

It is **highly recommended** that you start using [`SDK version 3.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/) as all the new features are/will be available in the new SDK.

**UPDATE**

Please see code below. It fetches 100 documents from collection at a time.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;

namespace SO68439632
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var endpointUrl = "https://accountname.documents.azure.com:443/";
            var authorizationKey = "authorizationkey==";
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var databaseId = "database-name";
            var containerId = "container-name";

            string continuationToken = null;
            string collectionUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, containerId).ToString();
            do
            {
                var feed = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
                           collectionUrl,
                           new SqlQuerySpec("select * FROM c WHERE c.Level = 2"),
                           new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 100, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, RequestContinuation = continuationToken }).AsDocumentQuery();
                var result = feed.ExecuteNextAsync().Result;
                continuationToken = result.ResponseContinuation;
                var itemsCount = result.Count;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total items fetched: {0}; More results available: {1}", itemsCount, !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken)));
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you did FirstOrDefault(). I m expecting multiple documents with my filter condition

Comment: I just copied the code from the link I shared in my answer :).

Comment: one problem here is createDocumentQuery do not have continuation token parameter in it. so that force me to read all documents at once instead reading MAXItemCount at a time

Comment: You should be able to specify continuation token in `FeedOptions`.

Comment: Please check [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.requestcontinuation?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_RequestContinuation).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235059/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-zzzsharepoint).

Comment: Updated my answer with working code sample. HTH.