# How to get continuation token in below Azure function for cosmos db trigger

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have below code which is going to copy 100 items at a time from one container of cosmos db to another container. I would like to know how in my below code , I can get continuation token in order for my continuation token to not return null in do while loop. I have followed the below code because I want to get 100 records each time and copy and then run the query again instead of querying the whole database.

```
static async Task Main()
        {
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( endpointUrl ), authorizationKey );
            string continuationToken = null;
            string collectionUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( SourceDatabase, SourceCollection ).ToString();
            do
            {
                var feed = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(
                           collectionUrl,
                           new SqlQuerySpec( "select * FROM c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.ClassID)" ),
                           new FeedOptions {
                               EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                               RequestContinuation = continuationToken } ).AsEnumerable().Take(100);            
                foreach( var doc in feed )
                {
                    var data =(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( doc.ToString() );
                    string partitionkeyValue = string.Concat( data["ClassId"].Value<string>(), "|", data["Project"].Value<string>() );
                    data.Add( new JProperty( "PartitionKey", partitionkeyValue ) );
                    await client.CreateDocumentAsync( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                   SourceDatabase, TargetCollection ),
                   data );

                }
              
            }
            while( continuationToken != null );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query cosmos db document to filter documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439632/query-cosmos-db-document-to-filter-documents)

Comment: I have one question here.. On doing the way as suggested and I was doing same way, will it fetch 100 records at a time until all the records have been queried??

Comment: That's correct.